# Pyomo time-dependant model?

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm quite new to pyomo but I'm having a hard time figuring how to create a time dependant model and plot it on a graph. By time dependant I mean just a variable that assumes different values for each time step (like from 1 to T in this case).

I used this very simple model but when I run the script I receive in output only one solution. How can I change that?
I also have errors related to the constraint function but I'm not sure what's wrong
(ValueError: Constraint 'constraint[1]' does not have a proper value. Found . at 0x7f202b540850>' Expecting a tuple or equation.)

I'd like to show how the value of x(t) varies in all timesteps.
Any help is appreciated.

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import sys

model = AbstractModel()
model.n = Param() 
model.T = RangeSet(1, model.n)
model.a = Param(model.T)
model.b = Param(model.T)

model.x = Var(model.T, domain= NonNegativeReals)

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='N.csv', range='N', param=model.n)
data.load(filename='A.csv', range= 'A', param=model.a)
data.load(filename='B.csv', range= 'B', param=model.b)

def objective(model):
    return model.x

model.OBJ = Objective(rule=objective)

def somma(model):
    return model.a[t]*model.x[t] for t in model.T) >= model.b[t] for t in model.T

model.constraint = Constraint(model.T, rule=somma)

instance = model.create_instance(data)
opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
results = opt.solve(instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build up lists of the values you would like to plot like this:

```
T_plot = list(instance.T)
x_plot = [value(instance.x[t]) for t in T_plot]
```

and then use your favorite Python plotting package to make the plots. I usually use Matplotlib.